# SymmetricDS : exclude table synced to selective nodes

Tags: synchronization, symmetricds

From server, I sync tables (1, 2, 3, 4, etc) to all nodes A, B, C, etc.

On a new node D, I decided to sync only tables 1 and 2. Node A, B, C still sync all tables (1, 2, 3, 4, etc).

In this case how am I going to exclude tables 3 and 4 to sync to node D ?

Do I need to split out node D from the rest and create new config for it ?

Answer (score 1):

Create another node group (`sym_group`), add D to this group. Create a router (`sym_router`) that will sync tables to the newly created node group. Create triggers to router (`sym_trigger_router`) that will link the newly created router with triggers of tables 1 and 2.

Comment: Besides using new node group, is there no other setting I can twist ?

Comment: This is the simplest and most straight forward way. Ask more if got stuck

Comment: You could also turn on dataloader.ignore.missing.tables=true, although that is more for remote databases that are in flux and might not have a table configured yet.  It would work for what you describe though.

The "correct" way is to do as @BorisPavlović suggests ...